# How do I reverse geocode a large number of points in python?

Tags: python, geojson, geocode, shapely

Right now I have a GeoJson File and the following function using shapely:

It takes in a coordinate and returns the neighborhood name

```
    def get_neighb(lat, lon):
    """Input Latitude and Longitude, Returns Neighborhood Name"""
    point = Point(lon, lat)
    found = False
    for feature in geo_data['features']:
        polygon = shape(feature['geometry'])
        if polygon.contains(point):
            return(feature['properties']['neighborhood'])
            found = True
    if found is False:
        return('NA')

# Initialize list
tn = ['']*data.shape[0]
for i in range(len(tn)):
    tn[i] = get_neighb(data.latitude[i], data.longitude[i])
```

This works, but it is really slow, any thoughts on how I could speed it up, currently running it on 4,000,000 row.

Comment: just a minor nitpick, but you don't actually need the found variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid for example the heavy-duty machinery of a PostGIS database, it could be of interest to employ the [`rtree`](http://toblerity.org/rtree/) package as (as the documentation states) "cheapo spatial database". The idea would be mostly as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import product
from random import uniform, sample, seed
from rtree import index
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, box, shape
from shapely.affinity import translate

seed(666)

#generate random polygons, in your case, the polygons are stored
#in geo_data['features']
P = Polygon([(0, 0), (0.5, 0), (0.5, 0.5), (0, 0.5), (0, 0)])
polygons = []
for dx, dy in product(range(0, 100), range(0, 100)):
    polygons.append(translate(P, dx, dy))

#construct the spatial index and insert bounding boxes of all polygons
idx = index.Index()
for pid, P in enumerate(polygons):
    idx.insert(pid, P.bounds)

delta = 0.5
for i in range(0, 1000):
    #generate random points
    x, y = uniform(0, 10), uniform(0, 10)
    pnt = Point(x, y)

    #create a region around the point of interest
    bounds = (x-delta, y-delta, x+delta, y+delta)

    #also possible, but much slower
    #bounds = pnt.buffer(delta).bounds

    #the index tells us which polygons are worth checking, i.e.,
    #the bounding box of which intersects with the region constructed in previous step
    for candidate in idx.intersection(bounds):
        P = polygons[candidate]

        #test only these candidates
        if P.contains(pnt):
            print(pnt, P)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to find a strategy to not check every row. the simplest way to do this is probably to dump all the shapes into a geo-aware database and query it. Something like post-gis or elastic search.

Another strategy might be finding the centroid of all the  neighborhoods, and then using a KD tree to filter only the neighborhoods with nearby centroids.

Comment: There is also SpatiaLite. A spatial extension to SQLite which is a bit simpler to get running than PostGIS.